# How to get absolute values instead of percentages in Perf’s annotate view?

Tags: profiling, perf

#### Question

In Perf’s annotate view, the runtime consumed by each instruction is given on the left side as a percentage. Is there some option to have some absolute quantity (probably samples) displayed instead?

#### Background

I am using some C code with classical C arrays as well as with Numpy Arrays (for use in a Python module) and I want to compare the performances by having it run on some identical example cases. There are certain parts (e.g., initialisation) whose performance I know to differ and which I am not interested in. However, these affect the total runtime and thus render the percentage values for the other parts uncomparable – unless I want to transform the values myself. If I could access the total runtimes, I could easily compare the different variants piece by piece.

Comment: Have you tried `perf report`

Comment: @Miline: That’s how I usually get to the annotate view (though I am aware of `perf annotate`). Any not source-code based view is not sufficiently detailled for me.

Comment: `perf report -n` shows samples; use `perf record -F 1000` to set sample frequency to 1000 per second. `annotate` may also have `-n`... Easier way is to add timing directly to your code to have direct time to time comparison

Comment: @osgx: That is not a comment, but an answer, albeit a wrong one. `perf report -n` does not lead to samples being shown in annotate mode, `perf annotate` does not have `-n`. Adding time evaluations directly to my code would be a horrible idea as it destroys several compiler optimisations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the flag `-n` showing samples has been added to `perf annotate` [in 2017](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1ac39372e06f5009982aaaf890fc5bbd044bb047). I haven’t tested it yet though.